# XGBoost plot_importance cannot show feature names

Tags: machine-learning, xib, xgboost

I used the plot_importance to show me the importance variables. But some variables are categorical, so I did some transformation. After I transformed the type of the variables, when i plot importance features, the plot does not show me feature names. I attached my code, and the plot.
    dataset = data.values
    X = dataset[1:100,0:-2]

```
predictors=dataset[1:100,-1]

X = X.astype(str)
encoded_x = None
for i in range(0, X.shape[1]):
    label_encoder = LabelEncoder()
    feature = label_encoder.fit_transform(X[:,i])
    feature = feature.reshape(X.shape[0], 1)
    onehot_encoder = OneHotEncoder(sparse=False)
    feature = onehot_encoder.fit_transform(feature)
    if encoded_x is None:
        encoded_x = feature
    else:
        encoded_x = np.concatenate((encoded_x, feature), axis=1)
print("X shape: : ", encoded_x.shape)


response='Default'
#predictors=list(data.columns.values[:-1])



# Randomly split indexes
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(encoded_x,predictors,train_size=0.7, random_state=5)



model = XGBClassifier()
model.fit(X_train, y_train)


plot_importance(model)
plt.show()

[enter image description here][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/M9qgY.png
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the expected behaviour- `sklearn.OneHotEncoder.transform()` returns a numpy 2d array instead of the input  `pd.DataFrame` (i assume that's the type of your `dataset`). So it is not a bug, but a feature. It doesn't look like there is a way to pass feature names manually in the sklearn API (it is possible to set those in `xgb.Dmatrix` creation in the native training API).

However, your problem is easily solvable with `pd.get_dummies()` instead of the `LabelEncoder` + `OneHotEncoder` combination that you have implemented. I do not know why did you choose to use it instead (it can be useful, if you need to handle also a test set but then you need to play extra tricks), but i would advise in favour of `pd.get_dummies()`